# User not logged in when WWW. is on URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

If I visit my site with out the www. prefix, login and then add the www., my user is not logged in any more, but if I remove the www., the user is logged in. It acts the same way if I do the Opposite. go to the web site with the www., login, and then remove the www. the user will not be logged in.

Here is the Login method and the authentication at the web.config.

```
public static void LogIn(userId)
{
   Item user = Framework.Business.Item.Load(userId);

   var _ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, _usrItm.ID, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(30), true, _usrItm.ID);

   string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(_ticket);
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));

}

<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name="k_Authentication" protection="All" timeout="120" cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="default.aspx" path="/" defaultUrl="/myweb.aspx"/>     
</authentication>
```

Comment: Are you hitting the web server directly or is the web server behind a proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll bet you a shilling to a guinea that the two answers about the domain setting of the cookies are correct +1s all around from me.

However. Most often the two sites are the same or they are not. If they're not, then you usually want the user to no longer be logged in, so don't change anything. If they are the same, then set one to permanently redirect to the other. As well as making this problem go away, you also gain some SEO benefits, benefits for people's history records being more consistent, and reduced pressure on shared caches. So I'd suggest that approach. I'd only deal with the matter of the domain set on the cookie if the two are separate-but-related, and sharing the log-in between them is appropriate.

Comment: well, they are the same. so do you suggest that I use a redirect?

Comment: @ShadowG Yes. As well as making this particular matter a non-issue, it would have the other advantages I mention. They're none of them earth-shattering, but they are all pluses, and it's as little if not less work to do the necessary IIS work as to change your code to set the cookies differently.

Comment: Tkx Jon, I think this is the better solution for what i want to.

Comment: what do you suggest, doing the redirect by  codebehind or webconfig?

Comment: I'd do it by IIS. Set up a new website that is set to serve all domains except the "good one", and for it to be a permanent redirect and not "exact destination" (so that `http://domain1/examplePath` goes to `http://domain2/examplePath` rather than `http://domain2/`). Then it doesn't even need to be part of the .NET application at all. The easiest code to debug is no code at all :) (Not that IIS settings can't be fiddly, but when they're done, they're done). If you already have redirect logic in either the code-behind or the web-config it might be easier just to add to what you've got though.

Answer (score 3):

There is probably a problem with the domain of your cookie. `www.example.com` and `example.com` are not the same domain.

You'll have to set the [Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.domain.aspx) property to `www.yourdomain.com` manually to share the cookies.